# I'm getting this error in python: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'". I'm using tkinter, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a simple rock-paper-scissors game and I'm getting an error in this line: result.set(" "). This line should clear an entry box when a button is clicked. How do I fix his issue?

```
result = StringVar()
compRandom = random.randint(1, 3)
compPick = compRandom.get()


def reset():
    result.set("")
    userTake.set("")

Entry(root, text=result, font='arial 10 bold', bg='turquoise2', width=50).place(x=25, y=250)
Button(root, font='arial 13 bold', text='PLAY', padx=5, bg='cornflower blue', command=play).place(x=170, y=190)
Button(root, font='arial 13 bold', text='RESET', padx=5, bg='cornflower blue', command=reset).place(x=90, y=310)
Button(root, font='arial 13 bold', text='EXIT', padx=5, bg='cornflower blue', command=exit).place(x=250, y=310)

root.mainloop()
```

The error code I'm getting is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/57797/PycharmProjects/Tutorial/Tkinter GUI Tutorial/19 - Rock Paper Scissors.py", line 61, in reset
    result.set("")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'
```

Comment: What is done to `result` variable prior to running `reset`? Do you use `get()` method on it?

Comment: I use `result` in this (it continues for other possible variations of the game): `if userPick == compPick:
        result = "Draw"
    elif userPick == "Rock" and compPick == "Paper":
        result = "You lose, the computer chose paper!"`

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  Better provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment with update. Ok, this is exactly where you went wrong:

```
if userPick == compPick:         
    result = "Draw"     
elif userPick == "Rock" and compPick == "Paper":
    result = "You lose, the computer chose paper!"
```

When you originally create your `result` variable you make it specifically a `StringVar` type that Tkinter can work with. But when you directly assign string values to it as you did in this `if/else` it becomes a regular `str`.

Now, `StringVar` has a `set()` method but `str` doesn't and this causes the error. What you should do is:

```
if userPick == compPick:         
    result.set("Draw")
elif userPick == "Rock" and compPick == "Paper":
    result.set("You lose, the computer chose paper!")
```

This will keep `result` as StringVar type.